# How to add a delimiter (#) in front of "any digits + a delimiter" in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, insert, delimiter

Hi I am new to python.

Current List:

```
current_list = ['Good 33912#This ice 989 cream is so sweet1345#That's a very good bar']
```

I want to have:

```
new_list = ['Good #33912#This ice 989 cream is so sweet#1345#That's a very good bar']
```

I want to add a delimiter(#) in front of "some digits and hash(#)" wherever found in the list. Please help

Comment: That isn't a valid string. You've got an unescaped `'` in the middle of a single-quoted literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` for searching and substituting string patterns (using back reference):

```
import re

current_list = ["Good 33912#This ice cream is so sweet1345#That's a very good bar"]

new_list = [re.sub(r'(\d+#)', r'#\1', i) for i in current_list]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
["Good #33912#This ice cream is so sweet#1345#That's a very good bar"]
```

Here is [explanation of regex string](https://regex101.com/r/fXNpn0/1) on Regex101.